# How to stop a specific Apache Felix bundle using java

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, apache-felix

I would like to know how to stop a specific bundle in the Apache Felix Web Console running only java code.

For example: I want to be able to retrieve a bundle, let's say by name, and stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From console:

1. `find 'bundle-name'`  //display bundles , get the id from here.
2. `stop 'id'`

From code:

1. First get the bundle object using [PackageAdmin.getBundles(name)](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/service/packageadmin/PackageAdmin.html#getBundles%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
2. Call [Bundle.stop](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#stop%28%29) on that bundle.

EDIT:
To get the PackageAdmin object:

```
ServiceReference ref = context.getServiceReference(PackageAdmin.class.getName());
PackageAdmin pa = (ref == null) ? null : (PackageAdmin) context.getService(ref);
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! Sorry I am really new to this, but how do I create the PackageAdmin object so that it has access to all the bundles hosted on my server?

Comment: i have updated answer with sample code to get package-admin refernce

Comment: also see this for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785588/how-to-discovering-types-exported-by-osgi-bundle-without-installing-activating?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: so what is the context object referring to? BundleContext?

Comment: Is it possible to get the BundleContext from outside the Felix OSGI environment?